# IList<string> passed to IEnumerable parameter

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, ienumerable

My brain is not working at all this morning so I hope someone can clear this up for me.

I have a little helper method that checks if an IEnumerable is null or has no items.

```
public static class ParameterGuard
{
    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmtpy<T>(T enumerable, string argName) where T : IEnumerable
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);
        if (enumerable.HasCountOf(0))
            throw new ArgumentException(Resources.ExceptionEnumerableEmpty, argName);
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(string arg, string argName)
    {
        if (arg == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);
        if (arg.Length == 0) 
            throw new ArgumentException(Resources.ExceptionStringEmpty, argName);
    }
}
```

I also have a small data structure for sending emails

```
public class EmailOptions
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public List<string> To { get; set; }
    public List<string> Cc { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsHtml { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to validate the To property using the ThrowIfNullOrEmpty method I get an exception.

```
  private MailMessage CreateEmail(EmailOptions options)
  {
        ParameterGuard.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(options.To, "To");
        ...
  }
```

**Exception**

```
The best overloaded method match for 
ParameterGuard.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

I would have thought that as the [IList<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class implements IEnumerable that this would work.

I would appreciate someone clearing this up for me.

Comment: If it is a copy/paste of the code, it might be because the first function is called `ThrowIfNullOrEmtpy`, not `ThrowIfNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: Are you sure? We cant reproduce the problem

Comment: @SWeko ; You're right. It's a typo. Do you want to create and answer for the points

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized (there was a non-obvious typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the code, and if both methods are indeed overloads, the generic version is (correctly) used.

In the code that is pasted, the first function is called `ThrowIfNullOrEmtpy`, not `ThrowIfNullOrEmpty`, so it is a simple misspelling.

---

This LINQPad code:

```
void Main()
{
  CreateEmail(new EmailOptions());
}

private void CreateEmail(EmailOptions options)
{
  ParameterGuard.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(options.To, "To");
}

public static class ParameterGuard
{
      public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T>(T enumerable, string argName) 
        where T : IEnumerable
      {
          Console.Write("Generic Version");
      }

      public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(string arg, string argName)
      {
          Console.Write("String Version");
      }
}

public class EmailOptions
{
    public List<string> To { get; set; }
}
```

returns *"Generic Version"*

Comment: Thanks... Slowly bangs head against desk :-)

Comment: @PhilMurray, why use two methods? string also implements `IEnumerable` (and IEnumerable<char>)!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a generic method like you used, you a normal method:

```
public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmtpy(IEnumerable enumerable, string argName);
```

The generic is not necessary.

Second of all. The methods have different names. It might just be a typo:

`ThrowIfNullOrEmtpy` vs `ThrowIfNullOrEmpty`

Comment: I have changed it as above but it still does not compile with the same exception

Comment: @PhilMurray Did you try to fix the spelling?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string argName)
{
    ...
}
```

As mentioned above you will have a mistake in you first method name.

Answer (score 0):

`string` also implements `IEnumerable`, you can use only one method:

```
public static class ParameterGuard
{
    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string argName)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);
        if (!enumerable.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("test");
        ParameterGuard.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(list, "list");
        ParameterGuard.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("string", "str");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your methods signature as follows:

```
public static class ParameterGuard
{
    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(IEnumerable enumerable, string argName)
    {
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(string arg, string argName)
    {
    }
}
```

Your two methods had a small typo and that is what was probably causing the confusion.. This way you should call the method with the enumerable.